# Read text file using R into one column

Tags: r, file

I'm using:

```
x<-read.table(file,sep="")
```

in order to read a space-delimited numbers from a .txt file, but I receive the data back in multiple columns because the text file contains multiple lines (whose data is no different but of the same type).
How can I read all of the numbers in the different lines into one column only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `?scan`:

```
x <- scan(file, what = "numeric")
```

or something simiar, depending on the structure of your file, should work. You might need to check / adjust the `sep` parameter.

Description of `scan`:

> Read data into a vector or list from the console or file.

If you want `x` as a column in a data.frame, you can do

```
dat <- data.frame(x)
```

afterwards.